# Where I can find a complete reference of openejb.xml?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, ejb, openejb

Do anyone know where I can find a **complete** reference of `openejb.xml` configuration file from [OpenEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/)?

Comment: http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/annotations-xml-and-defaults.html http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doc shows all configureable objects, their properties and their defaults.  As well as the syntax on how to "instantiate" one via either the openejb.xml file or via properties.

http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/containers-and-resources.html